# Joining table to union of two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `orders` and `oldorders`. Both are structured the same way. I want to union these two tables and then join them to another table: `users`. Previously I only had `orders` and `users`, I am trying to shoehorn `oldorders` into my current code.

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(user) AS cnt
    FROM orders o
        LEFT JOIN users u 
        ON u.userident = o.user
    WHERE shipped = 1
    AND total != 0
    GROUP BY user
```

This finds the number of nonzero total orders all users have made in table `orders`, but I want to this in the union of `orders` and `oldorders`. How can I accomplish this?

```
create table orders (
    user int,
    shipped int,
    total decimal(4,2)
);
insert into orders values
    (5, 1, 28.21),
    (5, 1, 24.12),
    (5, 1, 19.99),
    (5, 1, 59.22);
create table users (
    username varchar(100),
    userident int
);
insert into users values
    ("Bob", 5);
```

Output for this is:

```
+----------+-----+
| username | cnt |
+----------+-----+
|   Bob    |  4  |
+----------+-----+
```

After creating the `oldorders` table:

```
create table oldorders (
    user int,
    shipped int,
    total decimal(4,2)
);
insert into oldorders values
    (5, 1, 62.94),
    (5, 1, 53.21);
```

The expected output when run on the union of the two tables is:

```
+----------+-----+
| username | cnt |
+----------+-----+
|   Bob    |  6  |
+----------+-----+
```

Just not sure where or how to shoehorn a union into there. Instead of running the query on `orders`, it needs to be on `orders union oldorders`. It can be assumed there is no intersect between the two tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to `union` this way:

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(user) AS cnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM orders 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM oldorders
) o
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userident = o.user
WHERE shipped = 1
AND total != 0
GROUP BY user;
```

First get the combined orders using `UNION` between `orders` and `oldorders` table.

The rest of the work is exactly same what you did.

---

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27600/1/0)</kbd>

---

**Note:**

`Left join` doesn't make sense in this case. Orders for which the users don't exist then you will get `NULL   0` as output. This doesn't hold any value.

If you want `<user,total orders>` for all users including users who might not have ordered yet then you need to change the order of the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: That lower case "o" just after the parenthesis, seemed to make the difference for me, though I can't find any documentation on it.